# uiscrollView drag at his father another uiscrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, drag

I created a uiscrollview over another uiscrollview, the first has horizontal scrolling and the other Vertical Scrolling, the problem is that when I drag the second uiscrollview at top, it drag the father view with it(first uiscrollview), I don't want that effect, What could I do??.

Thanks for your asks.

Answer (score 0):

Use directionalLockEnabled property. Set it to TRUE while creating scrollviews.